# How to correctly configure the Kubernetes Dashboard via Ingress-Nginx on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm getting the error:

```
[lua] certificate.lua:89: call(): failed to set DER cert: SSL_add0_chain_cert() failed, context: ssl_certificate_by_lua*,
```

when configure ingress to serve kubernetes dashboard on GKE. This trouble realated only to Dashboard. In other namespaces simular configuration work fine. I mean with the same SSL certificate.

**Kubernetes version:** v1.14.7-gke.10

**Ingress-controller version:** 0.26.1

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: gke-dashboard.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - gke-dashboard.example.com
    secretName: example-ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of Ingress is correct. The key was in the SSL certificate bundle file.
I use a chain of certificates in one `crt` file that contains 5 certificates.

*Example snippet is:*

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF4zCCBMugAwIBAhIMUCJSvK6eipIjbvq7MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEwxGzAJ
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIETTCCAzWgAwIBAgILBAABBAAABRE9wNjEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwVzELMAkG
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEMTCCAxmgAwIBAgILBAAAAhhBMYnGOdwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwTDEgMB4G
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIELzCCAxegAwIBUGILBAASOMEBL07hNwIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwVzELMAkG
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEDjCCAvagAwIBAgILBAATEXTBHkSl82UwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwVzELMAkG
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In my bundle, I have a couple of unnecessary overlapping certificates. This why I had an error in the procedure of converting to DER format.

**After removing unnecessary certificates the trouble was resolved.**

By the way, such a bundle worked fine in **Ingress-controller version 0.20.0**. 
This why in my troubleshooting I have thought that there no errors in my certificates.

*Maybe this information will be helpful for someone.*